# VBA pasting based on cell vale

Tags: vba, excel

I have two worksheets I am working with.

Once called Data other 2018-2019

I want to paste the value from cell m22 (data) into row 3 (2018-2019) if the value in row 2 (2018-2019) is equal to that in cell m1 (data).

how do i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Public Sub PasteBasedOnValue()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim source As Worksheet
    Set source = wb.Sheets("Data")

    Dim dest As Worksheet
    Set dest = wb.Sheets("2018-2019")

    Dim valueToLookFor
    valueToLookFor = source.Range("M1")

    Dim valueToPaste
    valueToPaste = source.Range("M22")

    Dim rowToSearch As Integer
    rowToSearch = 2

    Dim rowToPaste As Integer
    rowToPaste = 3

    Dim maxCols As Integer
    maxCols = 256

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 1

    Do While c <= maxCols
        If dest.Cells(rowToSearch, c) = valueToLookFor Then
            dest.Cells(rowToPaste, c) = valueToPaste
            Exit Do
        End If
        c = c + 1
    Loop


End Sub
```

I'm interpreting your spreadsheet as looking like this screen capture below.  Based on your response, that's not exactly what it's like.  So if you could paste a screen capture of the real spreadsheet, I could modify my code accordingly.

[image: My interpretation of your spreadsheet]

Comment: this didn't work didn't exactly - this pasted into first column in  that row (probably my fault for explaining badly i think i confused rows and column  ... anyway not to worry though i swapped my columns and rows around as i know how to paste into row based on a value just not sure how to with columns (i asked this wrong in question).

Comment: Edited my answer with a screen capture of what I _thought_ your spreadsheet looks like.  If I could see what it actually looks like, I can edit my code.  But if you got it to work, then we can consider this closed!